# how to get an event when element.style is updated by user

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know if there is any event that is triggered when user updated inline css in element.style. I have tried mutationobserver but it also triggered when DOM is updated by some script on AJAX pages. I need an event/ method when user added something in element.style in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Do you mean you want to distinguish between 'dev tools' and 'ajax changes' for element styles?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Yes, can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You can only detect if [DevTools is open](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect). Beyond that, there is no way to know what is caused by DevTools or extensions.

Comment: How to detect when devtools is open?

Comment: How you are too sure? there may be some hacks?

Comment: To detect, check the source of the package I linked to. Or just use the package. Yes, I am completely sure there is no method to detect what you want.

Comment: @Garbee there must be some sort of event fired when the user changes a a style in the style panel that the dev tools code listens for

Comment: What would make you think that?

Comment: the dev tools code is open source, i feel like there has to be some trigger that can be tapped into to know when dev tools is updating the inline CSS or changing html. even if its not documented, there must be a way

Comment: There is not. The DevTools does not fire events into the page context, that would be wrong. Them being "Open Source" is irrelevant. All that means is, you can look at the code and confirm what I am saying  is true. "there must be a way" does not magically create one. Debugging tools are built to *not interfere* with the execution context. Think of it like a tap in between the page and the browser engine. It is in between and its modifications only talk one-way, which is back to the engine. Then based on that the page context changes. But, it does not send information forward into the page.